# How to use if statement in pandas to round a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data frame looks like this.

```
 a           d         e
0 BTC  31913.1123   -6.5%
1 ETH   1884.1621  -18.8%
2 USDT     1.0       0.1%
3 BNB    294.0246   -8.4%
4 ADA      1.0342  -14.3%
5 XRP      1.1423  -10.5%
```

On column d, I want to round the floats in column d to a whole number if it is greater than 10. If it is less than 10, I want to round it to 2 decimal places. This is the code I have right now `df1['d'] = df1['d'].round(2)`. How do I had a conditional statement to this code to have it round based on conditions?

Comment: something like `df[df.d>10]['d']=df[df.d>10]['d'].round(2)` ?

Comment: `df1.d = np.where(df1.d < 10, df1.d.round(2), df1.d.round())` This rounds to 2 decimal places if less than 10, rounds to integer otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1['d'] = np.where(df1['d'] < 10, df1['d'].round(2), df1['d'].round())
```

Comment: Can you please clarify why you didn't close this as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column) question?

Comment: @MustafaAydın - good idea.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31173785/7116645

Taking reference from above answer, you can simply do like following

```py
df['d'] = [round(x, 2) if x > 10 else x for x in df['d']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple statements like this:

```
df1['d'][df1['d']>10]=df1['d'][df1['d']>10].round()
df1['d'][df1['d']<10]=df1['d'][df1['d']<10].round(2)
```